# Value of c in a density function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I've been trying to figure out how the answer was obtained with this integral and I'm completely stuck.  Please help explain how was this integrated to get to the answer...

For positive integer n, consider the density function

$$
\mathbf f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
cx^n(1-x^n), & 0\le x\le1\\
0, & otherwise\\
\end{cases}
$$

Determine the value of c in terms of n

I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbf f_n(x) = 1$

and from here, I was able to integrate (and hopefully I'm right, I'm horrible at calculus):

$$
\mathbf C\left[\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right]\Bigg|_{x=0}^{x=1} = 1
$$

I'm not sure what it means when the questions says "in terms of n"

The answer says:
$$
\mathbf F_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2n+1}{n}x^{n+1} - \frac{n+1}{n}x^{2n+1}, & 0\le x\le1\\
\\
\qquad\qquad 0, & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$
where $\mathbf c = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{n} $

Can someone please help me figure out how we got to this response?  A step by step on the integral would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your valuable time in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. The constant $c$ depends on $n$. You have
$$\int_0^1 cx^n(1-x^n) dx = 1\implies c \left(\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right)_{x=0}^{x=1} = 1 \implies c \cdot \dfrac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)} = 1$$
This gives us $c = \dfrac{(2n+1)(n+1)}n$, which is what you need. Hence, the probability density function is
$$f_n(x) = \dfrac{(2n+1)(n+1)}n x^n (1-x^n)$$ and the cumulative distribution function is
\begin{align}
F_n(x) & = \int_0^x f_n(t) dt = \dfrac{(2n+1)(n+1)}n \cdot \left(\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right)\\
& = \dfrac{2n+1}n x^{n+1} - \dfrac{n+1}n x^{2n+1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you.  I see that once $\mathbf c$ was obtained, we just had to plug it in... I haven't done these things in years.. so could you explain how $ x^{n+1} - x^{2n+1} $ ended up being equal to n? basically I'm not sure of the algebra that led to the integrated answer to $\mathbf c\frac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}=1$  I'm assuming the values of the integral limits were plugged in there.. but still kinda lost when I try to do it myself. (Thanks again!)

Comment: @Amit Plug in $x=1$ to get $$\dfrac1{n+1} - \dfrac1{2n+1} = \dfrac{(2n+1)-(n+1)}{(n+1)(2n+1)} = \dfrac{2n+1 - n -1}{(n+1)(2n+1)} = \dfrac{n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}$$ Plugging in $x=0$ gives us $0$.

Comment: perfect.. that helped me get it. Thank you so much for your help!